# Removing email account prompts to remove from other computers

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, email

So I added my @att.net email address a while back and decided to remove it from OS X Mavericks Mail. When I clicked to remove it, it prompted me if I wanted to delete this email account from iCloud on this computer or on all computers. It also gave me a list of all the computers associated to my iCloud account. However, a lot of those computers don't even exist. How can I edit this list of computers associated to my iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

Go to [iCloud Devices](https://www.icloud.com/#find), sign in, click on "all devices", select the one to remove and click erase .

Comment: Those devices do not appear there.

Comment: Well then I would just change my password, that would solve it too. Do the names of the devices sound familiar to you?

Comment: Yes, they all seem like my device names but then again, they are generic like MacBook Pro or Mac Mini.

Comment: Oh, yeah if there is standing something like <yourname>'s MacBook Pro or <yourname>'s Mac Mini thats totally fine, its the Apple way of naming the Devices.